# Excel 2007 enable macros for a single excel document

Tags: excel, vba

Is there anyway a user can have macros enabled by default for a single workbook but not other ones? It is annoying you constantly have to enable them every time you open a particular workbook. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set trusted locations (folders) from which files can be opened without asking for enabling macros: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010031999.aspx

Comment: ...so f'in' miserable.  Excel 2007 security model, not your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In case, it is a workbook created by you then you can add your digital certificate to it. Digital certificate created by you will be trusted in your machine. Digital Certificate can be created by the tool listed in MS Office tools(start menu). And after creating digital certificate, you can attach it to your workbook in vba editor in excel.

Comment: For some inane reason my organization recently prohibited the digital signing of macros, but that is still the best solution IMO. I will go with bouvierr's solution since that seems to be the best alternative.